# Should I return class-specific types from my model to my controller?

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller

I am creating a workout tracking app to learn Swift and iOS development.  I haven't written code in 15+ years since college, so I'm new to this MVC thing.  Any guidance is welcomed, but specifically I have a question about best practices for how to communicate between model and controller.

My model (class name "Exercise" below) has its own types (e.g., "Weights", "Reps"), and it feels wrong to return those types back to my controller to build the view.  Is my intuition right? Should I abstract this one level higher so the controller requests values instead of class-specific data structures?  Or is this totally normal for MVC?

Here is some code to demonstrate what I'm doing now, which feels wrong.  The wrong part in question is in configureView().

The Model:

```
class Exercise {

    var name = "placeholder name"
    var formNotes = "placeholder notes"
    private var repLog: [repLogEntry] = []
    private var currentWeights = Weights(warmup25: 0, warmup50: 0, heavy: 0)

    init() {
        // some test data
        name = "Squat"
        formNotes = "Grasp the bar 1 inch outside knurling\nPull bar apart while squeezing shoulders back"
        self.recordExercise("16-04-20", weight: 135, reps: Reps(firstSet: 10, secondSet: 8))
        self.recordExercise("16-04-22", weight: 135, reps: Reps(firstSet: 11, secondSet: 9))
        self.setWeights(135)


    }

    // data to be recorded
    private struct repLogEntry {
        var date: String
        var weight: Int
        var reps: Reps

    }

    // reps always come in pairs
    struct Reps {
        var firstSet: Int
        var secondSet: Int
    }

    // weights of the exercise
    struct Weights {
        var warmup25: Int
        var warmup50: Int
        var heavy: Int
    }

    func recordExercise(date: String, weight: Int, reps: Reps) {
        let newRepLogEntry = repLogEntry(date: date, weight: weight, reps: reps)
        repLog.append(newRepLogEntry)
    }

    func setWeights(newWeight: Int) {
        currentWeights.heavy = newWeight
        currentWeights.warmup25 = Int(Double(newWeight) * 0.25)
        currentWeights.warmup50 = Int(Double(newWeight) * 0.50)
    }

    func getCurrentWeights() -> Weights {
        return currentWeights
    }

    func getLastWorkoutReps() -> Reps {
        return repLog.last!.reps
    }

    func getLastWorkoutDate() -> String {
        return repLog.last!.date
    }

    func getLastWorkoutWeight() -> Int {
        return repLog.last!.weight
    }  
}
```

And Controller:

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var detailDescriptionLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel?

    let Squat = Exercise()

    var detailItem: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
            // Update the view.
            self.configureView()
        }
    }

    func configureView() {
        // Update the user interface for the detail item.
        if let detail = self.detailItem {
            if let label = self.detailDescriptionLabel {
                label.text = detail.valueForKey("timeStamp")!.description
            }
        }

        let currentWeights = Squat.getCurrentWeights()
        let exerciseName = Squat.name
        let formNotes = Squat.formNotes
        let warmup25Text = String(currentWeights.warmup25)
        let warmup50Text = String(currentWeights.warmup50)
        let heavyText = String(currentWeights.heavy)
        let lastWorkoutReps = Squat.getLastWorkoutReps()
        let lastWorkoutDate = Squat.getLastWorkoutDate()
        let lastWorkoutWeight = Squat.getLastWorkoutWeight()

        label?.text = "\(exerciseName)\nWarmup (25%): \(warmup25Text)\nWarmup (50%): \(warmup50Text)\nHeavy (100%): \(heavyText)\n\(lastWorkoutDate) Reps @\(lastWorkoutWeight): \(lastWorkoutReps.firstSet) and \(lastWorkoutReps.secondSet)\n\nForm Notes:\n\(formNotes)"

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.configureView()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MVC what you're doing is 'fine'. You have separation of Model, View and Controller and the Controller is mediating between the Model and the View.

In MVC the Controller is usually managing all of the layout of the data on the view and all of the user interaction on the view, so it can get big and messy. Sometimes you'll pass the Model to the View and have the View configure itself, this makes the Controller simpler but isn't good MVC.

You can consider using MVVM - Model View ViewModel - which is an extension of MVC. Basically it takes the logic of how to display the Model data out of the Controller and puts it into a ViewModel, which is provided to the View for it to configure itself. This simplifies the Controller but also insulates the View from the Model.

So, your ViewModel would have your `text = "\(exerciseName...` code, but that's it. It just knows how to take a Model object and produce the text which should be displayed. It has no idea where it's going to be displayed. The View is configured with this ViewModel, so it can get the data it needs but it has no idea where it came from. The Controller is the middle man creating the ViewModel and passing it to the View.

Comment: So passing these data structures from Model to Controller is compliant with MVC.  That helps.